# Complex Eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, inner-products

I was trying to solve the eigenvalues and vectors of the following matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0& 0&1 \\ 
 1& 0 & 0\\ 
 0&1  & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I found the eigenvalues to be 
$\omega_1 = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $\omega_2 = \frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\omega_3 = 1.$

I easily found the eigenvector for the $\omega_3$. but I got stuck on the complex eigenvector, specifically solving the linear system resulting from the eigenvector-eigenvalue equation. For example, I found the following for $\omega_1$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 -\omega_1& 0&1 \\ 
 1& -\omega_1 & 0\\ 
 0&1  & -\omega_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 \\ 
 x_2\\ 
 x_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

the resulting system is then:
\begin{align*}
 \left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)x_1+x_3&=0 \\ 
 x_1+\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)x_2&= 0\\ 
 x_2+\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)x_3&= 0.
\end{align*}
I substituted $1$ for $x_3$ and obtained the following normalized vector

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
1\end{bmatrix}$$

however in the solution manual of the book the answer is :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I am not sure what the mistake I did. I tried dotting this with what I found to see if mine is in the same span, but the dot product resulted in a zero value. Could someone show what I am doing wrong here. I suspect it has to do with the way I solved the system of equation since I am not familiar with complex systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that there is an error? The second vector is the first one multiplied by $\frac{-1+\sqrt3\,i}2$. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: but why the inner product is zero ?

Comment: @NegativeTension The inner produc of *what*? You should be aware of the fact that the usual inner product, in $\mathbb{C}^n$, is the one defined by$$\bigl\langle(x_1,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\bigr\rangle=x_1\overline{y_1}+\cdots+x_n\overline{y_n}.$$

Comment: I took the inner product of my answer with that from the book. The result came up as a complex number and not 1. However I checked the modulus and turns out to be one. Does that mean if I have a complex eigenvector, then any vector "parallel" to it produces an inner product result of modulus one?

Comment: @NegativeTension I did not understand your question. However, I think that you may want to know this: if $v$ is an eigenvector and if $\omega\in\mathbb C$ is such that $|\omega|=1$, then $\omega v$ is also an eigenvector and $\|v\|=\|\omega v\|$.

Comment: So which vector from the above should I pick. I mean if the condition of the eigenvector is to be normalized, does that mean I am free to pick either one?

Comment: @NegativeTension Yes. Both of them have norm $1$.